# angular: convert rtf to html and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rtf

I have some strings formatted in rtf, 
I need to edit them in my webapp and save back in rtf.

the strings look like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
 \viewkind4\uc1\pard\qj\lang1040\ul\b\f0\fs16 string \ulnone\b0 string
 \par }
```

Is there any npm package to do it?

Comment: Hi @ar099968 did you find anything for this ?

Comment: @SohanSoni nope...

Comment: did someone find something?